# How to delete rows in a bigquery table using golang

Tags: go, google-bigquery, delete-row

I am trying to delete data from Bigquery table using Google cloud function in golang.
I have been successful with insertion , but unable to do delete. Based on some docs and googling, I understand I need to use DML, but not sure how do I actually write the code to perform delete operation.
[Golang client doc](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery) is not very helpful, nor is big query docs when it comes to delete selected rows.

A golang code snippet would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you use streaming API or loading files to tables.
In general if you need to delete data from big query you are not using the right tool.
If you use small amount of data you should not use big query and if you use big amount of data, do not use delete on any storage. Use event sourcing.
For example use row id and status and filter all id's with status deleted.

Comment: @ZAky, Yes, I am using streaming API to load csv file into GBQ table (Ref: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/bdc987b4624a0939603bb9f0a74eb2b815aa6577/bigquery/snippets/table/bigquery_table_insert_rows.go ). I need to update/delete the rows, based on the result of cloud function processing. Is there a better way to do it using cloud function?

Comment: @ZAky, I can filter the rows based on status. However, my status update depends on the output of cloud function.

Comment: You are not using streaming. you are using loading. That's okay.
Again, if you are using huge amount of data use event sourcing.
https://eventuate.io/whyeventsourcing.html#:~:text=Event%20sourcing%20is%20a%20great,sequence%20of%20state%20changing%20events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete rows, you issue a DML DELETE.  More details about the DELETE statement can be found here:  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#delete_statement

If you want an example of issuing a query, you can see the examples embedded elsewhere in the BigQuery documentation, or just go directly to source code snippets e.g. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/master/bigquery/snippets/querying/bigquery_query.go

If that's not sufficient, please clarify your question to provide more details about the issue you're experiencing (for example, the schema of your table and what you're trying to delete).

Comment: I already went through this code snippet. It a reference for firing select query and not DML.

Comment: The fundamentals are the same; only the query text differs.  Instead of a SELECT statement, you issue a DELETE statement.  You can also optionally skip row reading; DML statements don't return rows.